# How to find probability that exactly only one of three events in a sample space will occur

Tags: probability

As title states, I have 3 events  X, Y, Z in a sample space  each with a different probability of occurring, and I wanted to find the probability of exactly one of them happening.
For reference, Z is independent of X and Y, while X and Y are dependent.

I know for just two events (say X and Y), I would use the formula:
$P(X) + P(Y) - 2P(XY)$
Is there a similar way to solve for finding one of three events?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: Add up the area you want to calculate! [image: Venn]

Comment: So would this give me the correct answer: $P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - 2P(AB) - 2P(BC) - 2P(AC) - P(ABC)$ ? Or do I not need to subtract $P(ABC)$, since it's already covered in $2P(BC), 2P(AC), 2(AB)$?

Comment: Well, how many times have you counted $ABC$? It's counted with a + in A, + in B, + in C, -2 in AB, -2 in BC, -2 in AC, and you want it counted 0 times overall.

Comment: So I should add 3(ABC) to the above equation and that'll give me 0 times overall, it seems, right?

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Answer (score 1):

What you want should be:

$$
P(\text{Exactly one event})=P(X)+P(Y)+P(Z)-2P(X\cap Y)-2P(X\cap Z)-2P(Y\cap Z)+3P(X \cap Y \cap Z)=P(X)+P(Y)+P(Z)-2P(X\cap Y)
$$
since $X, Y$ are independent of $Z$. You need to add $3P(X\cap Y\cap Z)$ since you subtract it six times ($2P(X\cap Y)$, $2P(X\cap Z)$ and $2P(Y\cap Z)$).

Edit: Corrected my answer. This time it should be correct...

Comment: Even though Z is independent of Y and X, doesn't $P(XYZ)$ exist, and needs to be subtracted, along with $P(XZ)$ and $P(YZ)$?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Removing my answer for now. Thanks!