# Finding the probability of exactly one Events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I just wanted to mention that in the other question that is posted, they have mentioned that there is independence between the events. In here, there is nothing has been assumed.

Events $A, B, C$ are such that at least one of them occurs. Moreover, $P(A|B)=P(B|C)= P(C|A)= \frac{1}{2}$, $P(B \cap C)= 2 \, P(A \cap B) = \frac{4}{3} \, P(C \cap A)= 2 \, P(A \cap B \cap C)$. Find the probability that: (i) Exactly one events $A,B$ and $C$ occurs. (ii) Only B occurs

What I have come with so far was this: Since events $A, B, C$ are such that at least one of them occurs, then $P(A \cap B \cap C)=1$. Then I tried to translate each one of the given things in the question, such as $$P(A|B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}= \frac{1}{2}  $$ $$P(B|C)= \frac{P(B \cap C)}{P(C)}= \frac{1}{2}$$ $$P(C|A)= \frac{P(C \cap A)}{P(A)}= \frac{1}{2}$$.Then I use the three above given equations,

(i) $$ P(A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c})+P(A^{c} \cap B \cap C^{c})+P(A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c})= P(A)+ P(B)+ P(C) - 2 P(A\cap B)- 2P(A \cap C)- 2P(B\cap C)+ 3 P(A \cap B \cap C)$$ Then, 
$$ P(A \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c})+P(A^{c} \cap B \cap C^{c})+P(A^{c} \cap B^{c} \cap C^{c})= 3 P(A \cap B \cap C)$$ Then I tried the fact that $P(A \cap B \cap C)= P(A)+ P(B)- P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$ No matter how I would I move things around, I would still have one thing missing. Thank you for helping!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find probability that exactly only one of three events in a sample space will occur](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375057/how-to-find-probability-that-exactly-only-one-of-three-events-in-a-sample-space)

Comment: $P(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c)=0$ since we are told "at least one of them occurs."  Then also notice that $P(A\cap B^c\cap C^c)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$.  Can you explain why that line is true?  Think of the original proof of inclusion-exclusion.  Can you do something similar for the other terms?

Comment: Also note, you write in one of your lines "*Since events A,B,C are such that at least one of them occurs, then P(A∩B∩C)=1*".  This is incorrect.  Since at least one of them occurs we know that $P(A\color{red}{\cup}B\color{red}{\cup}C)=1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, If I would do so something similar what you have written, you would arrive to the sum of all of them which I have already up there.

Comment: Seems you are right. First probability equals $4.5P(A\cap B\cap C)$ and second equals $P(A\cap B\cap C)$. So numerical value for $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ is missing.